# Would this question about when it's better for a Pact of the Chain warlock to have their familiar attack be an on-topic bounded list question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, dnd-5e, list-questions

Recently, I asked this question: [For a Pact of the Chain warlock, is choosing to have their familiar attack generally the worse option for the warlock's action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170567/35259)

As I mention at the end of the question, I realised half way through writing it that it would likely have been an unbounded list question if I had kept it as it was, so before submitting it, I instead asked if my overall assumption was wrong, which I felt was a more stackable question. It seems to have been received well enough so far, and I'm still finding the answers helpful.

However, I was wondering if the question I was originally going to ask would have been an off-topic unbounded list question after all, or whether there were some additional constraints I could have added to make it more bounded? In other words, I might ask another, more specific question in addition to the one asked (I won't change that one now, I'm happy with it as-is).

Specifically, I'm playing as a Pact of the Chain Archfey warlock, and because I love playing into themes, I will (ideally) never summon anything other than a fey Sprite. Given that I've made this choice, I want to know how to get some more use out of this Sprite in combat. I'm also not planning on multiclassing, so this will be a single-class warlock. Perhaps if I kept it to a specific range of levels (since I'm not so interested in Tier 3 and above)?

Would constraints like that be enough to make such a question on-topic? Or is the question that boils down to "what are all the ways I can get use out of my sprite in combat" too inherently unbounded and off-topic? Is there anything else I can do to make it on-topic?

Comment: Related main question: [What can a familiar actually do?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51911/52137). Not sure whether it's useful as an example or actually covers your question.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Thanks. I had found that one before, and was hoping for tactics more specific to Sprites, since that Q&A is quite generic and doesn't go into detail about the fact that Sprites can go invisible or put people to sleep, etc.